# What is the relationship between IV&V professionals, Testers and QA engineers?

Tags: testing, validation, qa, sdlc, verification

In the context of SDLC, I know that **Verification and Validation** is about verifying the deliverable input from previous phase and validating the output of the current one.
And that testing is a phase among the SDLC phases.

Based on my research, I found from [UToronto lecture notes](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sme/CSC340F/slides/18-VandV.pdf) that:

> V&V performed by a separate contractor

Which means that [IV&V](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/ivv/home/index.html) ([Independent Verification and Validation](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sme/papers/1996/NASA-IVV-96-015.pdf)) professionals are externally involved in SDLC, and thus have nothing to do with the testing phase.

On the other hand, I find on [another course](https://www.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs795SD/s13/Public/vAndV/vAndV-slides.pdf) that:

> Testing is the most common, but not the only form of V&V

Which means testers are involved in IV&V.

This makes me confused about whether both testing phase and IV&V are made by same person (let's say QA engineer) or the persons doing IV&V are not involved in the testing stage.

Does the job V&V professional exist in the software industry? What relationship exists between QA engineers, testers and IV&V?

How is the V&V process involved during the project management: is it performed continuously within SDLC in the early stages or in the last stages?

Also does the SDLC include IV&V as a stage?

Comment: If you downvote, at least leave a comment, so I can further improve the question.

Comment: Can you add some more context about where you have seen the V&V term used? it sounds as though its a niche phrase, but for all I know it might be common place in industry X or field Y

Comment: I think people are downvoting because they have not heard of the term

Comment: @Ewan Should I change it to "Verification & Validation"?

Comment: @Ewan I mentioned two lecture notes in the V&V context

Comment: I think you should include that somewhere yes. But just investigating Dr Steve Easterbrook (formally of NASA) where the use the term exensively

Comment: https://www.nasa.gov/centers/ivv/home/index.html

Comment: yeah the links are good but old. (and in comic sans?!) add the NASA link so people believe tis a real thing and not just an academic invention from 10 years ago

Comment: also I would add some of Dr Easterbrooks cat pictures. no one can downvote a cat http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sme/cats.html

Comment: @Ewan Thanks so much for the link you shared. Now I realize that I was wrong for the abbreviation I used, it shall be *IV&V*, right?

Comment: possibly. You know I think you should email the Dr and ask him to post an answer. That would be super cool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Software verification and validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_verification_and_validation) are all the activities that ensure that the software fulfils all the needs and requirements for its intended purpose.  As such V&V is part of the larger set of [Quality Assurance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_assurance) activities (the latter also include activities to improve the quality, beyond the area of quality control to which V&V belongs)

The best known of these activities is of course testing, which verifies that the software works well, produces the expected results, is usable, and with acceptable performance. Of course this activity can be highly automated, even if usability tests and acceptance tests may require human involvement in near operating conditions.

But testing is not the only verification.  Code review for example is another QA activity, that verifies if the code is robust, and meets some quality criteria that are expected to facilitate future maintenance. Another kind of verification is related to security.  These kind of code reviews might be required to ensure that no undesired stealth behavior was hidden in the software (e.g. spying functions sending data to a foreign country once it is in operation), or that no vulnerability was implanted on purpose.

Nowadays, the V&V should no longer be considered as being necessarily a sequential step in a waterfall-like SDLC. These activities can be integrated smoothly in the day-to-day activities (e.g. embedded in the *definition of done*) in agile processes.

[Independent V&V](https://www.nap.edu/read/2222/chapter/4) is another (expensive) thing.  This is often found in the context of mission critical systems (e.g. aircraft systems, factory system in a pharmacological company, etc..) and government acquisition process. The reason is that team members (or staff members of a supplier) may have unconscious bias, or apply incomplete verification procedures (procedure might even be flawed because of purely economic consideration that are not appropriate for systems on which human lives depend on).  This is why an [independent](http://logapps.com/2013/07/independent-verification-and-validation/) team might be required.  It is to ensure that V&V is carried out as objectively as possible and with state of the art expertise.

So V&V and IV&V are highly related.  It is just that the second must be performed by a different economic operator in view of a proper [segregation of duties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_duties).  Note that in some cases V&V or even independent V&V could be subject of legal requirements.

Answer (score 4):

The relationship... doesn’t exist.

Modern software development generally doesn’t have discrete phases where you take and validate some input, do some work, and then pass it down the assembly line. And these days even having a separate role for testers or other quality assurance work is more and more rare.

At the scale necessary for most software, the verification process is automated and included in the continual deployment process. There are occasionally dedicated professionals that automate those tests, but they are just QA engineers or Software Develoment Engineer in Test (SDETs). The labels don’t much matter, but I’ve never heard V&V used.

Comment: also never heard of V&V.

Comment: @Ewan every engineer must know V&V.

Comment: @kais after reading the links I know what you _mean_ by v&v but I never heard the term before or seen any job adverts using it. Perhaps its just a particular industry or something?

Comment: @Telastyn V&V includes inspection techniques (for spec, artifacts, code) which I found that it can be by a separate contractor for the sake of independent technical opinion. So these inspection tasks are performed by QA engineers?

Comment: @Ewan In my knowledge in other engineering disciplines, there is the job "Test Engineer" which is in charge of these V&V tasks. In SWE I find most of jobs called "Software QA Engineer" or "Test & Validation Engineer". I'm not sure if "V&V engineer" job exists, maybe it doesn't.

Comment: I doubt that CI/CD would completely avoid V&V for mission critical software in embedded aircraft systems, nuclear power-plants and other highly regulated application areas (like GMP governed industries), where verification and validation are either legally mandatory steps or contractual requirements related to huge liabilities (and sometimes CD is not even an option).

Comment: @Christophe the thing is if V&V is considered a stage of the SDLC as we know it today, or if it's an independent audition of the software developed by 3rd parties, in which case, it would not be part of the SDLC. Whatever my customers do with the binaries I release, is out of my accountability and hence responsibility as Software Engineer. In other words, I might build cars, but whatever Euro Ncap do with my cars to test'em is no part of my activity, business or accountability. It's someone else business.

Comment: @Laiv Before a car manufacturer sends a car to Euro NCap for IV&V, the car already underwent in-house V&V. It’s the same for software: before you deliver something, you’ll make sure that it works („we value working software more than...“). The question of who does the verification & validation does not alter the fact that it‘s part of the process. You wouldn‘t exclude software development from SDLC because part of it would be subcontracted to a third party, would you?  V&V is nowadays mostly embedded and integrated in other activities and not a distinct isolated step, but it‘s still here

Comment: if it's integrated then that fits with @Telastyn's answer. We (devs) do it mostly with automated testing which is performed countless times in our workstations and at least once in CI/CD pipelines. That's why regarding software engineering I either see the relationship between QA engineers and V&V professionals. Basically, because we don't have such a role or field. We (developers) assume the V&V all the time. I got the feeling we are comparing different roles from different industries, that's why it's hard to find relationship. Relationship doesn't mean or implies similarities.